# Selenium -xpath creating

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I'm struggling with finding the xpath for the "Next" button that I need in order to automate the scraping process...

Just in case it's the rel = "next" one.

```
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get('https://autoplius.lt/skelbimai/naudoti-automobiliai?make_id=43&model_id=186&make_date_from=1999&make_date_to=2005')
cookie = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')
cookie.click()

Next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[text()="Kitas"]/a')
Next.click()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The xapth `//li[text()="Kitas"]/a` is not highlighting any element in the DOM. [You can refer this link to find unique locators](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/).

You can use below locators for <kbd>Next</kbd> button.

Xpath:

```
//div[@class='page-navigation-container']//a[@class='next']
```

CSS Selector:

```
div.page-navigation-container a.next
```

```
# Imports Required for Explicit wait

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://autoplius.lt/skelbimai/naudoti-automobiliai?make_id=43&model_id=186&make_date_from=1999&make_date_to=2005")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()

next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='page-navigation-container']//a[@class='next']")
next_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to right click on the element in the inspection tool. Once you right click, hover on copy and click 'Copy XPath'. I have attached a screenshot of the process. Let me know how it goes!

[Copy XPath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAxiY.png)